# GTK Glade: Hierarchy Editor

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gnome, glade

I'm using Glade 3.20.  I've created a liststore and a listview.  The liststore has three columns; a `gint`, a `gchararray` and another `gint`.

I right-click on my `TreeView` object and select `Edit...`.  The 'General' tab shows the columns I've defined in the liststore.  I select the 'Hierarchy' tab and click the '+' button.  This creates a new view column called `column`.  I right click on that and select 'Add child text'.  Nothing happens.

Is this a known problem with glade 3.20?  Am I doing something daft?

Comment: And have just built glade 3.21 with the same result.

Comment: check modern ui branch on github maybe solved there

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately its a bug. I think it was introduced around Glade 3.19.0. Copy pasting a cell renderer from an older glade file will work though or if added manually by editing the xml file:

Example cell renderer pixbuf :

```
<object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn1">
   <property name="title">column</property>
   <child>
      <object class="GtkCellRendererPixbuf" id="cellrendererpixbuf1">
         <property name="visible">False</property>
         <property name="stock_size">3</property>
      </object>
      <attributes>
         <attribute name="icon-name">0</attribute>
      </attributes>
   </child>
</object>
```

I've just prepared a simple glade file containing all the default cell renderers that you can copy paste, inside glade, to your glade file. Just go to the widget hierarchy, copy the renderer, go to your widget hierarchy and under the TreeViewColumn, paste the copied renderer.

cell_renderers.glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.19.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.16"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkTreeView" id="treeview1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="vexpand">True</property>
        <property name="headers_visible">False</property>
        <property name="search_column">0</property>
        <child internal-child="selection">
          <object class="GtkTreeSelection" id="treeview-selection6"/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn8">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererProgress" id="cellrendererprogress1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn7">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererSpinner" id="cellrendererspinner1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn6">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererAccel" id="cellrendereraccel1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn5">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererSpin" id="cellrendererspin1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn4">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererCombo" id="cellrenderercombo1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn3">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererToggle" id="cellrenderertoggle1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn1">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererPixbuf" id="cellrendererpixbuf1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="treeviewcolumn2">
            <property name="title">column</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="cellrenderertext1">
                <property name="height">44</property>
              </object>
              <attributes>
                <attribute name="text">1</attribute>
              </attributes>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

This may be solved in upcoming glade versions, though.